# How to test a class using Qt objects

Tags: qt, googletest, googlemock

I am writing unit tests for my Qt based application but I struggle to find the correct way to test the behavior of a class properly. I have a SystemDateTimeUpdater class that possesses a QProcess object to update the system time.

```
class SystemDateTimeUpdater : public QObject
{
public:
  explicit SystemDateTimeUpdater(const QDateTime& dateTime, QObject* parent = nullptr)
    : QObject(parent), m_DateTime(dateTime)
  {
    m_Process.setParent(this);
    connects(m_Process);
  }
  /*...*/

  void updateSystemDateTime()
  {
    QString dateTimeISO = m_DateTime.toString(Qt::DateFormat::ISODate);
    QStringList arguments;
    arguments << "--iso-8601"
              << "-s"
              << dateTimeISO;

    m_Process.start("/bin/date", arguments);
    m_Process.waitForFinished(); 
    emit notifyFinished();
  }

signals:
  void notifyFinished();
  void notifySuccess();

private:
  QProcess m_Process;
  QDateTime m_DateTime;

  void connects(QProcess &process)
  {
    connect(&process, QOverload<int, QProcess::ExitStatus>::of(&QProcess::finished),
            this, [this](int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus)
    {
      if (exitStatus == QProcess::NormalExit && exitCode == 0)
        emit notifySuccess();
    });
  }
}
```

Of course, I don't want that my class under test tries to update the system datetime.
I have two *naive* ideas in mind.

The first is to inject an utility class that manages system paths. I can then mock this dependency and use QProcess to start a script that simply returns 0 to simulate success. That seems like an awkward solution to me, though.

The second idea I had is to inject the QProcess itself to loosen the coupling with my class. But I'm not entirely satisfied with this idea either. I would need to hide the QProcess behind an interface of my own in order to be able to mock it properly. If I have to do the same kind of work for every non trivial Qt class (eg. I use QDbus to monitor the battery), it seems like a lot of work and I'm sure there's some better way to do it. Moreover, if I multiply dependency injections, I am wondering how to manage that many dependencies for my classes. Should I have some kind of factory that relays ownership to the calling class? I suppose that's a whole different topic but I am still wondering about this.

I would be happy to read your input on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here's what I went for.

I made the `QProcess` be instantiated (could also have been a class member) by a `Process` class that inherits from an interface `IProcess`. My SystemDateTimeUpdater holds a pointer to the interface.
Basically, I have:

```
class IProcess : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  explicit IProcess(QObject* parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) {};
  virtual ~IProcess() {};

  virtual void start(const QString& program, const QStringList& arguments = QStringList()) = 0;

signals:
  void notifyStarted();
  void notifyFinished(bool success);
};

class Process : public IProcess
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit Process(QObject* parent = nullptr) : IProcess(parent)
{}
  virtual ~Process() {};

  void start(const QString& program, const QStringList& arguments = QStringList()) override
  {
    QProcess* process = new QProcess(this);
    QObject::connect(process, &QProcess::started, this, &Process::notifyStarted);
    QObject::connect(process, QOverload<int, QProcess::ExitStatus>::of(&QProcess::finished),
                     this, [=](int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus)
    {
      if (exitStatus == QProcess::NormalExit && exitCode == 0)
        emit notifyFinished(true);
      else
        emit notifyFinished(false);

      process->deleteLater();
    });
    QObject::connect(process, &QProcess::errorOccurred,
                     this, [=](){ qWarning() << process->errorString(); });

    process->start(program, arguments);
  }
};

class SystemDateTimeUpdater : public QObject
{
public:
  explicit SystemDateTimeUpdater(const QDateTime& dateTime, QObject* parent = nullptr)
    : QObject(parent), m_DateTime(dateTime)
  {
  }

  /*...*/

  void start()
  {
    if (isValid()) // private function that checks that the members are valid
    {
      updateSystemDateTime();
    }
  }

  void setProcess(IProcess* process)
  {
    if(m_Process)
        delete m_Process;

    QObject::connect(process, &IProcess::notifyFinished, this, &ISystemDateTimeUpdater::notifyUpdateFinished);
    process->setParent(this);
    m_Process = process;
  }

private:
  void updateSystemDateTime()
  {
    if(!m_Process)
    {
        qWarning() << "Process is nullptr. Abort update.";
        return;
    }

    QString dateTimeISO = m_DateTime.toString(Qt::DateFormat::ISODate);
    QStringList arguments;
    arguments << "--iso-8601"
              << "-s"
              << dateTimeISO;


    m_Process->start("my/date/command/path", arguments);
  }

signals:
  void notifyUpdateFinished(bool success);
  
private:
  IProcess* m_Process;
  QDateTime m_DateTime;
};
```

Now before calling the start function I need to set a process from some place.

```
  // My object has previously been initialized
  
  systemDateTimeUpater->setProcess(new Process); //systemDateTimeUpdater takes ownership of this ptr
```

I can easily mock it with gmock using the interface.

```
class MockProcess : public IProcess
{
public:
  MOCK_METHOD(void, start, (const QString& program, const QStringList& arguments), (override));
};
```

Here's two basic tests using the mock object.

```
TEST(SystemDateTimeUpdaterTest, StartSucceeds)
{
  SystemDateTimeUpdater updater(QDateTime(QDate(1992,7,17), QTime(7,45)));
  MockProcess process;
  EXPECT_CALL(process, start)
          .WillOnce([&process](){ emit process.notifyFinished(true); });
  updater.setProcess(&process);
  QSignalSpy finishedSpy(&updater, &SystemDateTimeUpdater::notifyUpdateFinished);

  updater.start();

  ASSERT_EQ(finishedSpy.count(), 1);
  EXPECT_TRUE(finishedSpy.takeFirst().at(0).toBool());
}

TEST(SystemDateTimeUpdaterTest, SetProcessObjectTakesOwnership)
{
    SystemDateTimeUpdater updater(QDateTime(QDate(1992,7,17), QTime(7,45)));
    MockProcess* process = new MockProcess;
    updater.setProcess(process);

    EXPECT_EQ(process->parent(), &updater);
}
```

Comment: It is not advisable for an interface class to be inherited from a concrete class, have you found any answers to this question?

Answer (score 0):

The standard way is to replace `m_Process` with a mock object that just saves how many times and with what argument what functions has been called. In this case I would test for `start` method. My approach would be:

1. Add setter and getter for `m_Process` (This is quite usual thing that you need to adjust your code to make it testable.).
2. Create class derived from `QProcess` overriding `start` and `waitForFinished` (do not forget make it `virtual`) and with additional functions `QList<QList<QString>> start_calls_arguments()` and `int waitForFinished_calls_count()`. `start` would just add argument lists to some internal list of lists, `waitForFinished` increments some internal counter, aforementioned new functions would return these.
3. Run your test and get your derived mock of `QProcess`, upcast it and check argument of `start` calls and count of `waitForFinished` calls.

Comment: The issue with your solution is that I would need to make `start` and `waitForFinished` virtual (just as you stated) in order to mock them properly. These class are part of the Qt framework and I can't change them.

Comment: Damn, you are right. Then the way can be to make your `SystemDateTimeUpdater` a template class and then instantiate it with `SystemDateTimeUpdater<QProcess>` for production and `SystemDateTimeUpdater<MockQProcess>` for the test. Would you consider this an acceptable answer and should I update it or should I delete it?

Comment: Ah, I considered doing that too (googletest refers to this as **Hi-perf dependency injection**). Sadly, the Q_OBJECT macro is not compatible with template classes. I tried to only templatize my function and create the object in this function (which would then be either a QProcess or a MockQProcess). However, my SystemDateTimeUpdated inherits from an interface (which I hid from the code snippet for concision sake and that I need to mock this utility class which is also used by other classes) and I want my `updateSystemDateTime` function to stay virtual... which is incompatible with templates

Comment: So what I did is create a `Process` class that inherits from an `IProcess` interface. My concrete class holds a QProcess object. I inject a pointer to this interface to my `SystemDateTimeUpdater` object so I can use a `MockProcess` that implements `IProcess`.
Not sure if this is the best way, it add a few extra classes but at least it allows me to mock the QProcess behavior that I need.

Comment: Nice, so basically using pointers to inject your dependency. Would you mind to write it as an answer for your own question to allow others benefit from it? My upvote would be granted then.